# Transitivity of the action of a normalizer on the set of fixed points

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group acting transitively on a set $X$ (from the left). Let $H$ be a subgroup. Denote by $S$ the set of fixed points of $H$. That is
$$S=\{x\in X\mid \text{$h\cdot x=x$ for all $h\in H$}\}.$$

Let $N=N_G(H)$ be the normalizer. If $x\in S$ and $n\in N$, then $H\le Stab_G(x)$. Hence
$H=nHn^{-1}\le Stab_G(n\cdot x)$, allowing us to conclude that $n\cdot x$ is also a fixed point of $H$. Therefore $N$ acts on the set $S$, and we have reached
my question:

> Is the action of $N$ on $S$ necessarily transitive?

Testing with small groups suggests this to be the case, but I am nowhere near seeing why this should always happen. It might also be false!

This question is my translation of a natural question from Galois theory into the language of group actions. Incarnations:  [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2184351/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4236207/11619).

[An answer by Derek Holt](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1060639/11619) shows that the answer is affirmative, if $H$ happens to be a Sylow subgroup of $G$. What happens in general?

Comment: I'd be flabbergasted if this were true. Give me a minute to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a counterexample, how about $S_4$ acting on the set of six pairs of points $\{ \{a,b\} : a, b \in \{1,2,3,4\}, a \ne b\}$.

The image of $(1,2)$ under this action has fixed set $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$. The normalizer of the subgroup $H$ of order 2 that it generates is the image of the subgroup $\langle (1,2), (3,4) \rangle$, which fixes both of those points. So it does not act transtiviely on the set of fixed points.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I tested $S_4$ with the wrong $X$ and my intuition was otherwise miscalibrated. I will let this stay open for a while in case somebody else wants to join in the fun.